Color nested bonds
In chemfig, I would like to represent the geometry of the complexes (in particular the fac/mer isomerism).
I can draw the complex: no problem.
However, I would like to better visualize the isomers by showing the planes formed between the two chlorines by red dotted bonds but I can't do it.
I would like to have a figure that would resemble this one in principle (do not rely on the absence of bonds in front and behind the plane, I took the image that most closely resembles what I am looking for)

\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{Co([:45]<:Cl?[a])([::135]<:H_3N)([::-45]<Cl?[b]?[a])([::-135]<H_3N)([:90]-Cl?[a]?[b])([:-90]-NH_3)}
\end{document}



The section 12, Connecting distant atoms, of the chemfig manual indicates that ? accepts an optionnal argument:
?[<name>,<bond>,<tikz>]

Use <tikz> to customize the bonds with some TikZ code. You can leave the <bond> field empty.
Example:
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{
  Co
  ([:45]<:Cl?[a])
  ([::135]<:H_3N)
  ([::-45]<Cl?[b]?[a,,thick, densely dotted, red])
  ([::-135]<H_3N)
  ([:90]-Cl?[a,,thick, densely dotted, red]?[b,,thick, densely dotted, red])
  ([:-90]-NH_3)
}

\end{document}


